# Is CP-1251 an extension to ASCII?

Tags: ascii

If I need Cyrillic characters in ASCII format that will imply that I will need an extended ASCII table, right? I want to know if cp-1251 is an extension of ASCII and if not what is it considered to be. I got a bit confused with searching google. In some places they say it is a codepage in other extension.

Also if I have cp-1251 character O with code 206 then the UTF-8 value of the same char will be 041E, right?

Answer (score 2):

"Extended ASCII" is an ambiguous term.

US-ASCII supports 128 values (the 8th bit is reserved) and does not support any Cyrillic code points. The first half of [Windows 1251](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305144.aspx) maps code points to the same range of values. The same is true of UTF-8. Therefore, any documents encoded as ASCII are legal Windows 1252, Windows 1251, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, *and a few other encodings*.

U+004F ( LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O) encoded as ASCII, Windows-1251 or UTF-8 will have the same octet value (`4F`) when viewed using a hex editor.

For natural language data most non-Unicode encodings should be considered [obsolete](http://www.siao2.com/2012/03/26/10286723.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a standard.  It is a 7 bit code.
It contains values in the range of 0 .. 127.
Everything else is not ASCII.

On a PC one can deal with [Code Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page).   You may be able to select a code page which contain the characters you are interested in.

It may be of benefit to look into [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html) which can support ASCII and pretty much any other character that was ever invented.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, ASCII is a 7-bit format that contains no Cyrillic characters.  Given this, one cannot truly have Cyrillic characters in genuine ASCII format.

CP-1251 is an 8-bit encoding that includes Cyrillic characters.  The first 128 characters of CP-1251 are the same as ASCII, so in that sense it is an extension of ASCII.  Ultimately, however, CP-1251 is just a character encoding, i.e. a mapping between characters and numeric values.

The Unicode family of encodings has the greatest momentum for modern internationalized applications at this time, with UTF-8 being the most popular due to its compact representation for basic ASCII characters.  Using Unicode fully requires being able to process multi-byte characters, including using more sophisticated algorithms for text-processing tasks like sorting, searching, and text comparison.

Unfortunately, character encoding is no longer as simple as it was when US-ASCII was king.  Of course, even then competitors like EBCDIC muddied the waters.

A few links that might help:

http://www.unicode.org/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305144

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251